# How to tell python to reload module whenever it sees import statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program to manage the flow of processing data. User can write code of several method to process data, called 'flow code', and tell my program to compare the result of each method. The code is executed by `exec`.

There's also a git repo containing functions to call, and user can import them in the 'flow code'.

My question is, because user can change repo between each execution, how to tell python to reload modules when it sees an import statement in 'flow code'? My current solution is that, before executing a line,  check type of all local variable of 'flow code' and reload it if the type is `ModuleType`. However, this is very inefficient. Is there any better solution, like hooks?

Someone said `imputil` can make hooks, but the documentation says:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The imputil module has been removed in Python 3.

And I'm using python 2.7

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you need to rethink the whole architecture; `exec` and `reload` are rarely the right way to do things.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then is there any way to create separate environment for the 'flow code'? (The flow code is made up by lines instead of a whole file.  it is actually a DAG graph, which each vertex represents some code and edge represents sequence. What's more, it's better if I'm able to cache local variables after executed some lines and later use those cache to continue.)

Comment: I'm sorry, there's just not enough information here to make any sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use reload method.

e.g.

```
>>> import test
>>> test.a
1
>>> test.a = 3
>>> test.a
3
>>> reload(test)
<module 'test' from 'test.pyc'>
>>> test.a
1
>>>
```

Comment: Note that `reload` won't affect names directly imported in the namespace, ie `from test import a; reload(test)` won't set `a` to the "reloaded" version of `test.a`.

Comment: I used it, but my question is how to know when to use it to make it efficient.